# Virtual PC LAMP Server

Tags: lamp, redhat, virtual-pc

I have a mirror of a RedHat6 LAMP server setup locally on my development machine (XP pro) for testing.

I am trying to configure it so I can connect to it. However I am having problems.

I've given the image a static IP address of 192.168.1.5. The httpd service is running, and when in RH6 I can view the apache test page by visiting http://192.168.1.5/.

I can also successfully ping the virtualpc from the windows cmd line. However when I try to visit the test page from Windows it eventually times out.

I have tried Shared Network, local only and the physical adapter in the VirtualPC settings. Only the physical adaptor will allow me to ping the virtual pc.

What do I need to do to be able to use it successfully as a test server?

**NOTE**: I can't replace RH6 with <*insert-your-favourite-distro-here*>, though if you can demonstrate a benefit switching from VirtualPC then I might do so.

Comment: From the command line, can you telnet to port 80? 

telnet 192.168.1.5 80

Comment: No. Times out after about 30 seconds with the message 'Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to open up port 80 through the firewall in RH6. I don't have RH6 running infront of me but I think it's in the menus in System Settings -> Security or something.

Answer (score 1):

Does your browser in windows use a proxy server? If so, make sure that 192.168.1.5 is in the exclusions list.

Comment: According to Firefox it says I am not using a proxy server.